# Async/await - cannot reach promise result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am trying to reach the Promise result in a Reactjs function component, but it does not work for me. When I return the function result I only get Promise. My goal is to return an object contained in [[Promise Result]].

```
const params = ['ACT', 'STBY', 'STBYH'];
const getActStby = async address => {
  const getActStbyParams = await getXhr({
    url: `./scripts/system_read_config?${xhrParam(address, params)}`
  });
  return getActStbyParams;
};
```

Then I call It later in a code and assigning to the object as a new property:

```
newItemEqpt.isAct = getActStby(getNetworkAddress(item.from.FROM, item.to.TO));
```

Output of these activities is "partially" okay. When I console.log the object, Promise is fulfilled, but what I wanted to is assigning the array of `parameters` in [[Promise result]] directly to `isAct` property. How can I do this?

```
isAct: Promise
 [[Prototype]]: Promise
 [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
 [[PromiseResult]]: Object
   parameters: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
   [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: `async` functions always return a promise so you need to `await` for `getActStby`, and then assign the result to that property.

Comment: try `newItemEqpt.isAct = await getActStby(getNetworkAddress(item.from.FROM, item.to.TO));`

Comment: `newItemEqpt.isAct = await getActStby(getNetworkAddress(item.from.FROM, item.to.TO));` call is outside the function. As far as I know `await` has to go together with async as a parent function. 
So I was trying to do something like this:
`newItemEqpt.isAct = async () => { await getActStby(getNetworkAddress(item.from.FROM, item.to.TO));};`
but it didn't work too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getActStby` declared as `async`, so you have to `await` for getting its results like so;

```
newItemEqpt.isAct = await getActStby(getNetworkAddress(item.from.FROM, item.to.TO));
```

To be able to use the `await` keyword like above, the function call to `getActStby` should also be made in an `async` function, otherwise you will have to chain the function with a `then` method and access the return value of that function by using a callback.